# GoLang, elasticsearch multiple query parameters

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I have a project in golang which fetches logs from elastiearch where our servers send logs. I have a problem with multiple query. 
**I want to query by two fields, where both must be found and filter result to get all these logs between two timestamps.** 
In the code below attaching `deploymentName` object into `Filter()`causes for no results at all.

```golang
import  ("github.com/olivere/elastic")


func main() {

client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL(*elasticUrl))


   //query by time
    timeQ := elastic.NewRangeQuery("@timestamp").From(from).To(to)

   //query by key named "component"
    componentQ := elastic.NewMatchQuery("component", *component)

    //query by key named "deploymentName", sam type as component
    deploymentQ := elastic.NewMatchQuery("deploymentName", deploymentName)

    //query object used for actual search later
    generalQ := elastic.NewBoolQuery().Should().
       Filter(timeQ).Filter(componentQ).Filter(deploymentQ)

        searchResult, err := client.Search().
                Index("some-index").
                From(from).Size(*chunk).
                Query(generalQ).
                Sort("@timestamp", true).
                Do(context.Background())
}
```

While if generalQuery is written like this, it works.

```
        //query object used for actual search later
    generalQ := elastic.NewBoolQuery().Should().
       Filter(timeQ).Filter(componentQ)
```

Comment: What makes query run correctly is replacing this:
``deploymentQ := elastic.NewMatchQuery("deploymentName", deploymentName)`` with: ``deploymentQ := elastic.NewMatchQuery("deploymentName.keyword", deploymentName)`` Not sure why it works or why this field needs .keyword.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently new with Elasticsearch, but this way actually works and return the specified components and deployments in a given time range.

```
timeQ := elastic.NewRangeQuery("@timestamp").From(from).To(End)
componentQ := elastic.NewTermQuery("component", *component)
deploymentQ := elastic.NewTermQuery("deploymentName", deploymentName)

generalQ := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
generalQ = generalQ.Must(timeQ).Must(componentQ).Must(deploymentQ)
```